# Google Map does not load properly everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Sometimes, the Google map does not load properly, and don't allow to insert a marker:

[image]

This is my code to create the map:

```
var companyCreateMap;
var companyCreateMapInitialZoom = 7;                 

function companyLoadInitialMap()
{
  companyCreateGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var companyCreateInitialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(companyCreateMapInitialCenterLat, companyCreateMapInitialCenterLng);

  var companyCreateMapOptions = {
    center: companyCreateInitialLocation,
    zoom: companyCreateMapInitialZoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

companyCreateMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(companyCreateMapCanvas), companyCreateMapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(companyCreateMap, 'click', updateMarkerCoordenatesOnClick);

companyCreateGetUserLocation();
}

function companyCreateGetUserLocation()
{
  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    browserSupportFlag = true;

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (companyCreatePosition)
    {
        var companyCreateCenterLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(companyCreatePosition.coords.latitude, companyCreatePosition.coords.longitude);

        companyCreateMap.setCenter(companyCreateCenterLocation);
        companyCreateMap.setZoom(17);
        companyCreateMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: companyCreateCenterLocation, map: companyCreateMap, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP     });
    },
    function (error)
    {
        // User did not accept to give location
        //handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag, error);
    });
}
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
else
{
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    //handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
}
}
```

This does not happen every time, only from time to time, and I get no errors in the console.

Any idea?

Comment: This is a small nit, but I would explicitly declare 'companyCreateMap' to be global.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's already global. I have updated the code with it.

Comment: What does your HTML/CSS look like?  Looks like your map doesn't (always) have a size.

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I need more tests to be sure. It seems that Google Maps "don't like" to be inside an element with display:none that is presented with a fadeIn()...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to trigger a map resize when the fade-in has completed.

```
$('#map-canvas').fadeIn(200, function() {

    // Trigger a map resize
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/1wc32skw/)</kbd>

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. The solution I found to avoid having the map in a dispay:none container is not really a solution, but yours is really great. Is it common to use this solution in my situation?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go when you resize / unhide the map canvas element.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much again for your help. I saw your project, it seems that we are Google Maps explorers :)

Comment: Hi @MrUpsidown I'm having a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793592/google-directions-map-not-loading-on-ipad-landscape-orientation do you think it's the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick. Are you loading the map in landscape mode and nothing shows? Or does this happen when you switch from portrait to landscape?

Comment: Hi, I tried to load the Map in Landscape and then rotate to Portrait and it appears only in Portrait. I have just done the test loading in Portrait (it works fine) and then rotate to Landscape and it desappears...

Comment: I have made another test in Safari for Windows and discovered that the map disappears when I start in full screen and I slowly reduce the height of the Browser and at a certain point, the map disappears...?!

Comment: Mmmh... sounds strange. Looks more like a CSS issue to me but I can't really tell. You could try to fire the resize event anyway and see if it helps and/or listen for the device orientation change and fire it there. Try and report here or on your question.

Comment: I tried to resize after loading it but it's not working. It not seems due to a resize problem because the image of the map desappears...it seems that it need a certain height to show-up...

Comment: Yes, you need to set a height to your map container. If you don't know it, then calculate it/set it with JS.

Comment: I think I found the problem, because of a lake of space, the element is "pushed" down so it desappears. I tried to put the map side by side with display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle and 50% for the map and 50% for the directions and both with height: 95% but now I don't now why the directions don't get flexible in height and they disappear when I reduce the height of the browser, any ideia why?